# realtime networking for games, interpolation issue

Tags: networking, real-time, multiplayer

I've been putting some thought lately into networking for real time, fast paced games. It seems that if you interpolate correctly then the hit calculation is done on the state that happened more than (p1.interp+p2.interp+p1.ping/2+p2.ping/2) ago from player2(p2)s points of view when the shooter is player1(p1).

The packet first goes to the server which takes p1.ping/2, then the server calculates it on the game state that has happened p1.interp + p1.ping/2 ago. The result of that calculation is send to the player2 which only sees it p2.interp later. It adds up even further because of the time it takes for all three sides to process things.

```
    player1            server             player2
       |                 |                   |
.------|_1.............actual.....|.....game state......|
|      |                 | ^                 |
|intrp |_2               | |                 |
|      |                 | |                 |
`----->|_3----ping/2     | |                 |
                  `------|_4----ping/2       |
                                    `------5_|-------.
                                             |       |
                                           6_|  intrp|
                                             |       |
                                           7_|<------‘
```

<sup>Excuse my poor ASCII art skills but I couldn't resist.

(I got home where I have Windows installed and I see how shit it looks here but hope you guys get the idea)</sup>

Assuming 50ms ping, 100ms interpolation it gives us more than 250ms summed up. This means that a player2 is seen approximately 250ms in the past by player1 but, assuming client prediciton, he sees himself in realtime. Is my logic flawed or is this just not a big deal?

Comment: Well, I've tried to fix that ASCII. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) as an answer to a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782902/networking-problems-in-games) question. Not sure if this is appropriate as an answer but I can't comment.

Comment: Well my question was somewhat based on that article.